# Python - Use variable to call object

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to call an object from a variable.  I know how to use getattr to call a function of an object using a variable but can't work out how to use a variable to define the object name.  I have dragged some example code below:

```
class my_class(object):
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var1 = var

var = "hello"
object_1 = my_class(var)

print object_1.var1 # outputs - hello

attribute = "var1"

# i can call the attribute from a variable

print getattr(object_1, attribute) # outputs - hello

object = "object_1"

# but i do not know how to use the variable "object" defined above to call the attribute

# now i have defined the variables object and attribute how can i use them to output "hello"?
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `object_1` and `object` are global variables, you may use the code below:

```
print(globals()[globals()['object']].var1)   # "hello" is printed
```

or this:

```
print(getattr(globals()[globals()['object']], attribute))    # "hello" is printed
```

where

`globals()['object']` represents "object_1" string

`globals()[globals()['object']]` represents `object_1` object.